# How to prevent automatic token refresh with Doorkeeper OAuth?

Tags: oauth, google-chrome-extension, doorkeeper

I'm using the Doorkeeper gem to provide OAuth in a Rails app. The client is a Chrome extension.

I have 'use_refresh_token' commented out in doorkeeper.rb, and 'access_token_expires_in' set to 1 minute. I thought that would force the client to re-auth after a minute. But re-auth is happening automatically, regardless of whether use_refresh_token is present or not.

With use_refresh_token present, a new row is added to 'oauth_access_tokens' every time the access token expires. No new row is added to 'oauth_access_grants.'

With use_refresh_token commented out new rows are added to both tables. Which I would expect if the client was manually re-authing. But it appears to be happening automatically--the user is granted access without having to re-auth the app through the OAuth login screen, as I'd like.

Apologies for my ignorance, I'm new to both Doorkeeper and OAuth and haven't found any clues on Google et al.

Comment: In researching this, I see that Google APIs support an approval_prompt param, which accepts a 'force' value. That's the behavior I'm trying to duplicate with Doorkeeper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OAuth 2.0 is working as it is sending authorization URI to authorize url to get the access token and while the user is not authorized to get token the server redirect him to login page, I think the point in your case that the expire in time is too short so the session opened when user entered username and password for first time still valid so when your client asking for new token it is getting it as the user is still loged in on the authorization server, you can change the time of session to be less than the token validity time and test it.

Comment: This was it, I'm kind of embarrassed to say--I was dealing with different subdomains, and didn't realize the user was still authed in. Since the user was still logged in, the oauth provider just refreshed the token. When I sorted out the subdomains, and properly logged the user out, it behaved as expected. Thanks Bobo.